# Trying to set UIControl objects' frames through a function

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to create a function to change the size of something like a UILabel or UIButton without having to type the three lines out every time. This is what I have.

```
-(void)setObject:(UIControl*)object SizeWidth:(NSInteger)width Height:(NSInteger)height
{
    CGRect labelFrame = object.frame;
    labelFrame.size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    object.frame = labelFrame;
}
```

However, when I give (UIControl*)object a UILabel, it says "incompatible pointer types". How can I fix this to work for anything I can put on a UIView?

Comment: A few style issues. Following Obj-C style conventions make it more efficient for others to read and comprehend our code. 

1. All method parameters should begin with a lower-case char.

2. `set` is used as part of `@property` synthesis and by convention your method name indicates setting a property named `object` to the value of `object` and then setting it's width and height. 

3. Most everything in Objective-C is an object... and you have a method called `setObject:` when you're clearly working with views? 

4. Why pass width and height when you can pass a CGSize?

Comment: I'm still a little new at this, but I'll definitely keep these in mind. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I figured that @aeubanks, that's why I'm trying to help. Trying to become out best is the whole point of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Label is not a subclass of UIControl.  You can use UIView in place of UIControl.

```
Here is the hierarchy for UILabel  
UILabel: UIView : UIResponder : NSObject

-(void)setObject:(UIView*)object SizeWidth:(NSInteger)width Height:(NSInteger)height
{
    CGRect labelFrame = object.frame;
    labelFrame.size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    object.frame = labelFrame;
}
```

One suggestion for you is, the method name seems kind of odd to me. You can write a simple category to update the size for UIView.  With the following category you can simply call

```
[myLabel setWidth:20 andHeight:20];
```

In    UIView + MyCategory.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (MyCategory)

- (void)setWidth:(NSInteger)aWidth andHeight:(NSInteger)aHeight;

@end
```

In    UIView + MyCategory.m

```
#import "UIView + MyCategory.h"
@implementation UIView (MyCategory)

- (void)setWidth:(NSInteger)aWidth andHeight:(NSInteger)aHeight;
{
    CGRect frameToUpdate = self.frame;
    frameToUpdate.size = CGSizeMake(aWidth, aHeight);
    self.frame = frameToUpdate;
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what MyCategory.h is. But your way seems very very simple and I definitely want to implement it. Thanks!

Comment: never mind, I looked it up and I got it now. Thanks so very much

Answer (score 1):

`UILabel` is not a subclass of `UIControl`, it inherits from `UIView`.

Try changing `UIControl` to `UIView`:

```
-(void)setObject:(UIView*)object SizeWidth:(NSInteger)width Height:(NSInteger)height
{
    CGRect labelFrame = object.frame;
    labelFrame.size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    object.frame = labelFrame;
}
```

(`UIControl` inherits from `UIView` anyway, and `frame` is a `UIView` property)

Answer (score 0):

And to address the actual problem you're trying to solve, I highly recommend using this set of helpers https://github.com/kreeger/BDKGeometry

Answer (score 0):

Following Obj-C style conventions (as selecting the right tools for the job) make it more efficient for others to read and comprehend our code. The Objective-C style here needs a bit of cleanup. See my notes after the source if you're interested. On to a more concise way to do this:

You can go the class method route (perhaps in a view manipulation class)

```
@implementation CCViewGeometry

+ (void)adjustView:(UIView *)view toSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGRect frame = view.frame;
    frame.size = size;
    view.frame = frame;
}

@end
```

or the UIView category route

```
@implementation UIView (CCGeometry)

- (void)resize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size = size;
    self.frame = frame;
}

@end
```

Style notes pertinent to code found on this page:

1. *All* method params should begin with a lower-case char.
2. `setFoo:` is used in `@property` synthesis & by convention your method name indicates setting a property named `object` to the value of `object`. You're setting the size, not the object itself.
3. Be explicit. Why have a method called `setObject:` when you know the general type of object being passed?
4. Width & height in UIKit are represented (rightly) by CGFloat, not NSInteger. Why pass width + height instead of CGSize anyway?
5. Try using class methods when state is not required. `+` is your friend. Don't fire up instances for every little thing (most singleton methods I see in ObjC code should be refactored as class methods).

The programmers that don't care about the little things end up with unmaintainable code—code that will slow them and those that come after them down. Convention and style matter a lot on any decent-sized project.